# Python How put relation data into mongodb+gridfs

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs

How save 1.000.000 web-pages with css,js,img-files into mongodb+gridfs? How to define a link between the page and html files?

Answer (score 1):

See here for general sql -> mongodb:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart

And embedding and linking specifically:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking

You should be able to apply this to GridFS as well.

Answer (score 1):

GridFS uses two collections to store data **files** contains the object metadata and **chunks** which contains the binary data.  You can extend that metadata in files in any way you wish as long as you don't interfere with the existing fields, so you can "tag" your objects to describe them in any manner you see fit and separate them any way you want - file type, content type, language etc.

This capability is even mentioned in the GridFS spec: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification

Alternatively, you can create an entirely separate collection yourself and refer to the the objects in that way (probably by storing the files _id).